# IBM Maximo Java API - Cannot filter MboSet by related attribute

Tags: java, maximo

This question pertains to the Java API of Maximo Asset Management.

To meet a business requirement, I must filter an MboSet by an attribute of a related object; to be specific, I need to filter a WORKORDER set such that only WO's with LOCATIONS containing a certain attribute value are selected (a custom attribute).

Using the "SetWhere" function, I am unable to filter an MboSet by a related attribute using the syntax "LOCATION.ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'VALUE'"... I swear I was able to do this using SetQBE. How can I do this using SetWhere?

Is there a better way? I don't want to store this value in the WORKORDER object and duplicate data. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind everyone... the answer (after failing to find one online) was simple, and uncovered through trial and error.

Suppose you want to filter a WORKORDER MboSet by an attribute belonging to a related object (in my case, a custom attribute on the LOCATIONS object). Logically, this is what you want to accomplish:

```
remoteMboSet.setWhere("LOCATION.CUSTOM_ATTRIB = 'VALUE'");
```

...to get the actual behavior and result, your syntax is as follows:

```
remoteMboSet.setWhere("LOCATION IN (SELECT LOCATION FROM LOCATIONS WHERE CUSTOM_ATTRIB = 'VALUE')");
```

Comment: Don't forget about a siteid filter, though if this is meant for a specific company, it might not matter.    The "setWhere" clause is literally setting the "where" clause of an SQL statement. The xyz in  "select * from <table> where xyz", so if it doesn't make sense / can't run in a query tool like that, then it won't work in that method call either. A "setQBE" on the other hand (as JPTremblay suggests) uses more of the business logic so you can actually use their dot notation. It also comes with more overhead, but that likely isn't a problem.

Comment: The "Logically, this is what you want to accomplish" bit should be worked into your Question to improve the quality of your Question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the dot notation with the QBE API to have filtering based on related objects.

This should work:

```
remoteMboSet.setQbe("RELATION.ATTRIBUTE", "='VALUE'");
```

This is in fact how the new REST API works internally.
https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/restguide/Maximo_Nextgen_REST_API.html#_filtering_data_using_where_clause

Answer (score 0):

In your own answer to your question, you said:

> Logically, this is what you want to accomplish
>
> `remoteMboSet.setWhere("LOCATION.CUSTOM_ATTRIB = 'VALUE'");`

What you are missing from that line is a colon `:` on the front of `LOCATION`. That's right: you can use bind variables in your where clause sent to `setWhere()`. Here's the quoted code adjusted:

```
remoteMboSet.setWhere(":LOCATION.CUSTOM_ATTRIB = 'VALUE'");
```